# What happens to coins that are sent to a public viewkey?

Tags: cryptonote, protocol

As the title states, if I sent moneros to the public viewkey instead of the right one (standard monero address), what will happen to them?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, since the CryptoNote protocol allows you to send coins only to a valid address which is a 95-character string representing a pair of public view key and public spend key. You must be misunderstanding what you've done with your wallet.

Answer (score 3):

A view key is not a valid address, and thus your transaction should be void.